# Django Added ForeignKey object in Custom User Model, when creating users im getting value error

Tags: django, django-models, valueerror, django-custom-user

Django Added ForeignKey object in Custom User Model, when creating users im getting value error
this is user model(AppUser) having foreignkey in it, the error is as folllowed, ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "AppUser.branch" must be a "Branches" instance.
tried with just instance also user = User.objects.create_user(email='admin@fmlk.com',branch=Branches.objects.get(name="Temp_Branch"))

```
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    secId = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=sec.token_urlsafe(16))
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branches,on_delete=models.SET(tempBranch),null=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
`    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['branch']
    objects = UserManager()
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, branch, password = None,**extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")
        if not branch:
            raise ValueError("Need Branch")
        email = self.normalize_email(email.lower())
        user = self.model(email = email, branch=    branch, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self.db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email,branch, password = None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff",True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser",True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active",True)
        return self.create_user(email,branch,password, **extra_fields)
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(email='admin@fmlk.com',branch=Branches.objects.get(name="Temp_Branch").id)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Varun/Spaces/spaces/core/manager.py", line 9, in create_user
    email = self.normalize_email(email.lower())
  File "/Users/Varun/Spaces/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 543, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Users/Varun/Spaces/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 283, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "AppUser.branch" must be a "Branches" instance.
```

Comment: Could you share your `Branches` model please ?

Comment: class Branches(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=False,null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=False,null=False)
    iso_label = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=False)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

Answer (score 0):

In this relation, I guess you need to pass the instance itself (the Branch object), not the id.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(email='admin@fmlk.com',branch=Branches.objects.get(name="Temp_Branch"))
```

simply delete the ".id" it should work.

Comment: trie that too, Got the following error.user = User.objects.create_user(email='admin@fmlk.com',branch=Branches.objects.get(name="Temp_Branch"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Varun/Spaces/spaces/core/manager.py", line 8, in create_user
    raise ValueError("Need Branch")
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Branches'

Comment: Because you get `None` or `0` when you get your `Temp_Branch`. Have you created it first with `Branches.objects.create()` ?

Comment: i had created it, ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "AppUser.branch" must be a "Branches" instance.